# How to calculate average with Pandas Dataframe using Cells from different rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that currently looks like this

Here is the `df.head()` and `df.tail()`

```
      Name  Count  Year Gender
0     John   9655  1880      M
1  William   9532  1880      M
2    James   5927  1880      M
3  Charles   5348  1880      M
4   George   5126  1880      M
           Name  Count  Year Gender
743745   Zykeem      5  2014      M
743746   Zymeer      5  2014      M
743747  Zymiere      5  2014      M
743748    Zyran      5  2014      M
743749    Zyrin      5  2014      M
```

It is the number of babies named that during that year. I want to calculate the percent change from the previous year. Is there a pythonic way of using pandas to do that simply or do I need to make a complicated loop.

Comment: Did you try either approach? This is a simple problem. Please edit your question with your current approach. Also how do you want the results to be tabled?

Answer (score 1):

First step involves getting groups. Then you can iterate over the groups, merge your DataFrames, compute your statistics and collect the result in another DataFrame:

```
perc_chng = []
keys = []

grouped = df.groupby('Year')
for name, group in grouped[1:]:
    try:
        prev = group.get(name - 1)
    except KeyError:
        prev = pd.DataFrame()
    merged = pd.merge(group, prev, how='outer', on='Name').set_index('Name')
    merged['perc'] = merged['Count_x'].difference(merged['Count_y']).\
        divide(merged['Count_y']).multiply(100)
    perc_chng.extend([])
    keys.extend(['{p}-{c}'.format(p=name-1, c=name)])

res = pd.concat(perc_chng, keys=keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot your data so it looks like this:

```
       John  Simon  Barry
1880     30      0      0
1930     20     10      5
1960     18      9      8
```

Then it's a simple diff, something like this:

```
df.iloc[1:] = 100.0 * (df.iloc[1:] - df.iloc[:-1]) / df.iloc[:-1]
df.iloc[0] = np.nan
```

Comment: Isn't iloc very slow on a large data frame like OP's?

Comment: @Khris: Why exactly would integer-based indexing be slow?  I've never heard of such a thing.  On the contrary, it may be the fastest type of indexing, plus it only creates a view.

Comment: I don't know if I have been using it wrong, but generally when I was trying to do things in different ways to find the fastest way, using pandas with loc or iloc was the slowest while using pure Python or Numpy and transforming back and forth to and from pandas was much faster.

Comment: @Khris: Do you mean you were looping and using `iloc` or `loc` repeatedly?

Comment: Exactly. Already learned that looping shouldn't be done with those.

Comment: @Khris: Right, so loops are bad.  But my code doesn't use loops.  `iloc` and `loc` are not slow--loops are slow.  The code in my answer will be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have the following DF:

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
      Name  Count  Year Gender
0     John   9655  1880      M
1  William   9532  1880      M
2    James   5927  1880      M
3     John   9000  1881      M
4  William   8000  1881      M
5    James   5000  1881      M
```

you can use `groupby()` followed by `pct_change()`:

```
In [14]: df['pct_change'] = df.sort_values('Year').groupby('Name').Count.pct_change() * 100

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
      Name  Count  Year Gender  pct_change
0     John   9655  1880      M         NaN
1  William   9532  1880      M         NaN
2    James   5927  1880      M         NaN
3     John   9000  1881      M   -6.784050
4  William   8000  1881      M  -16.072178
5    James   5000  1881      M  -15.640290
```